# Is there any way to run my containers periodically?

Tags: docker, go, multiprocessing, containers

I'm trying to write a program that from the main "server", calls for 2 "agents" that each one of them creates containers. Each container should run periodically and every 10 seconds print the time. The `create` command is taken from the Std.in as `<command> <PATH>`.

For example, I pass 4 containers to create, so `agent1` creates 2, and `agent2` creates 2.

My problem is that when I run this program I only see the second container from agent1 when I type `docker ps` I get only `mycontainer2`.
And only after I stop/remove `mycontainer2`, only then agent2 creates `mycontainer4`. (`mycontainer1` and `mycontainer3` wasn't created at all).
Probably the way I created them was wrong. Is there any way I can create all of them and let them run separately?

**Main "server":**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

type conf struct {
    Name string `yaml:"Name"`
    Amount int `yaml:"Amount"`
    Image string `yaml:"Image"`
}

func (c *conf) getConf() *conf {
    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("conf.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("yamlFile.Get err   #%v ", err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }

    return c
}

func isError(err error) bool {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    return (err != nil)
}

func showEnvStatus() {
    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "Hello from ShowEnv")
    // cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("some input")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The out put is: %q\n", out.String())
    return 
}

func createAgents(c conf){
    var workload = c.Amount/2
    var rightBroderAgent1 = strconv.Itoa(workload)
    var leftBorderAgent2 = strconv.Itoa(c.Amount- workload + 1)

    //invoke agent1. Args are the range of the containers numbers for names. (0 : workload)
    cmd1 := exec.Command("./agent","1", rightBroderAgent1, c.Name, c.Image)

    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd1.Stdout = &out
    err1 := cmd1.Run()
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println(err1)
    }
    fmt.Println("%q\n",out.String())

    //invoke agent2. Args are the range of the containers numbers for names.(workload+1 : Amount)
    cmd2 := exec.Command("./agent",leftBorderAgent2, strconv.Itoa(c.Amount),c.Name, c.Image)
    err2 := cmd2.Run()
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }

    return
}

func parseCommand(text string) ([]string){
    res := strings.Split(text, " ") 
    return res
}

func main() {
    i := 0
    for i < 1{
        var args []string
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        args = parseCommand(text)
        switch args[0] {
        case "create":
            var c conf
            c.getConf()
            createAgents(c)
        default:
            fmt.Println("Unknown command, try again")
        }
    }
}
```

############################# Agent file ##################

```golang
func main(){
    // Args[] structure : {FILE, left border, right border, container's name, image}
    left,_ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    right,_ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[2])

    for i := left; i <= right; i++ {
        fmt.Println(left, right)
        var name string = os.Args[3] + strconv.Itoa(i+1) 
        cmd1 := exec.Command("docker", "run", "--name", name, "-it", "-d", os.Args[4])
        cmd2 := exec.Command("docker", "cp", "showtime" ,name + ":/showtime")
        cmd3 := exec.Command("docker", "exec" ,name , "./showtime")
        
        // cmds := []*exec.Cmd{cmd1,cmd2,cmd3}

        err1 := cmd1.Run()
        if err1 != nil {
            fmt.Println(err1)
            os.Exit(2)
        }       
        err2 := cmd2.Run()
        if err2 != nil {
            fmt.Println(err2)
            os.Exit(2)
        }   
        err3 := cmd3.Run()
        if err3 != nil {
            fmt.Println(err3)
            os.Exit(2)
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked a Docker API https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/api  ?

Comment: You also probably want to build at image containing your binary; `docker cp` the program you actually want to run is a little unusual.  Then you can use the Docker API to create and run the container without needing to use debugging tools like `docker exec`.